# How to increase the quality strings drawn with Graphics2D?

Tags: java, string, resolution, graphics2d

After experimenting back and forth with Graphics2D vs. JPanels I have noticed that strings written on a JPanel are much higher resolution (less pixilated) then those drawn with g.drawString().

Is there any way to increase the resolution of strings drawn with Graphics2D?

Comment: Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/renderinghints.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you draw using `Graphics2D` directly, are you using `RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING` as mentioned [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/renderinghints.html)?

Comment: Beaten by seconds! Seconds, I tell you! :)

Comment: LOL. 1+ for the comment.

Answer (score 3):

Set the Graphics2D RenderingHints parameter, `RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING`, to `RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON` or one of the other constants that turn this anti-aliasing on.

Comment: Thank you immensely especially for such a quick fix! I was not even aware of setRenderingHints().

Comment: 24 seconds and I will